# How to get a correct scrolling using TkInter's text widget?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, textbox

I'm trying to program a simple GUI using the Text widget of TkInter and I'm stuck with a strange behavior when I scroll within it.

When I reach the end of the text, sometime, I get a blank line at the bottom of the widget (and sometime not)...

Here you can see the blank line :
[image: At the bottom : the blank line]

And this time, there's no...
[image: At the bottom : no blank line]

Or course I don't want to see this blank line.

Here is a simple snippet that illustrate my issue. Play with it : scroll up and down using the up/down arrows, the home/end/pageup/pagedown keys. 
At one time, you should see the blank line...

```
import sys,Tkinter

escape,up,down,home,end,pageup,pagedown = 27,38,40,36,35,33,34

class HText ( Tkinter.Text ):
    def __init__(self,parent,lines,w,h ):
        Tkinter.Text.__init__( self,parent )
        self.config( takefocus=True,width=w,height=h )
        self._len   = len( lines )
        self._index = 0
        self.config( state=Tkinter.NORMAL )
        for i,t in enumerate( lines ):
            self.insert( Tkinter.END,'%-4d : %s\n'%(i,t),'#%d'%i )
        self.focus( 1 )
    def focus (self,on):
        self.tag_config( '#%d'%self._index,background='#daf' if on else 'white' )
    def move (self,keycode):
        delta = { up:-1,down:+1,home:-self._len,end:self._len,pageup:-20,pagedown:+20 }.get( keycode,0 )
        index = max( 0,min( self._index+delta,self._len-1 ))
        if index != self._index :
            self.focus( 0 )
            self._index = index
            self.see( '#%d.first'%self._index )
            self.focus( 1 )

def Gui ( text ):
    self = Tkinter.Tk()
    self.bind('<Escape>',lambda e : self.quit())
    self.bind('<Key>'   ,lambda e : htext.move( e.keycode ))
    htext = HText( self,text.split('\n'),120,30 )
    htext.pack()
    self.mainloop()
    self.destroy()

Gui( open( sys.argv[0] ).read()*10 )
```

Do you see what I'm doing wrong ?
Is it a bug in TkInter ?

By the way, I'm using python 2.7 under Windows 7 x64.

Thank in advance for your time.

Hadrien

Comment: I doubt that this is the [mcve]. Please narrow it down better.

Comment: The default `Text` widget already produces a blank line in the end, how is above case any different?

Comment: Ok, here is shorter example, and 2 screenshots, with and with out the blank line.
But I dont understand `"The default Text widget already produces a blank line"`. Do you mean it's an expected behavior ?

Comment: It's not necessarily expected in default text, but also it has nothing to do with scrolling. It seems to be simply what you insert in the widget as string.

Comment: The solution seems pretty simple: just delete the trailing newlines.

Comment: In the above code solution is `htext.delete('end-1c', 'end')`. But you should be aware of what you're putting in your widget, so it's only a cope out if you don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the string insertion is done use this line to remove the last newline character:

```
htext.delete('end-1c', 'end')
```

Comment: I don't think so because the 2 behaviors (& screenshots) are seen with the same input.+ I just tried without the trailing newline, and I got the same thing....

Comment: This removes the empty newline for me with the code above you've provided if I put this line just before `mainloop`.

Comment: Yep, you're right! I add your line too, and I have no more blank line! I'm not quit sure to understand why...    But now, when I select the very last line, the colored background don't reach the right side of the widget. I stops at the end of the text. But it's already a big hep.

Comment: But what is that last char you remove with `htext.delete('end-1c', 'end')` ? I tried to remove the last char of the last line of my text, but I don't get the same result...

Comment: It was a newline `"\n"` that got removed for above code.

Comment: Of course ! me stupido ! It's not a newline from the input, but the one I add myself when I insert the lines...